# Laravel4 File Upload via XMLHttpRequest2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I am a beginner-to-intermediary programmer and got stuck with the following issue (really, couldn't find anything via search):

Laravel 4 uses the following algorithm to manipulate files, uploaded via a submitted form:

```
$file = Input::file('foo');
...
```

I am sending multiple files via XMLHttpRequest2 with an ability to monitor progress of each individual file. Here is the sample:

### HTML

```
<div class="div-files">
    <input type="file" class="input-files" multiple>
    <button class="btn-upload">Upload</button>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-upload").click(function(){
        var files = $(".input-files")[0].files,
            div_files = $(".div-files");
        if (files.length == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $(files).each(function(key, val) {
                div_files.append("<p>" + val.name + " <progress data-id=\"" + key + "\" value=\"0\" max=\"100\"></progress></p>")
                var data = new FormData(),
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                data.append("SelectedFile", val);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        console.log(request.response);
                    }
                }
                request.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                    $("progress[data-id=\"" + key + "\"]").val(Math.floor(100*e.loaded/e.total));
                }, false);
                request.open("POST", "/import");
                request.send(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### PHP

```
$file = $_FILES['SelectedFile'];
if ($file['error'] > 0) {
    return Response::json(array('status' => 'error', 'data' => 'An error occurred while uploading.'));
}
...
```

The problem is I want to manipulate the file in Laravel-ish way, to be able to

```
$file->guessExtension();
```

and

```
$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

and so on. But php treats

```
$file = $_FILES['SelectedFile'];
```

as another instance, and I cannot get it via

```
$file = Input::file('SelecteFile');
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why won't you use jQuery's $.ajax?

Comment: @RoboRobok, I tried, but could not get progress (loaded) out of it :(

Comment: @Antor, actually I developed my uploader with Laravel as well :) Input::file works fine for me there. If you have any problems, I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can track progress with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    xhr: function () {
        var result = {};

        result = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

        if (typeof result.upload === "object") {
            result.upload.addEventListener(
                "progress",
                function (e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        // here you have e.loaded and e.total
                    }
                },
                false
            );
        }

        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! After your comment I went into some digging and did the following ajax:

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/import",
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
      // e.loaded and e.total
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  }
});

Comment: `$.ajaxSettings.xhr()` is more reliable than `new window.XMLHttpRequest()`.